# Case sensitive Menu Hooks

Tags: routes

I was checking the access logs and could spot that most of the pages were linked from other sites with different cases. `node/add` is same as `NODE/ADD` and all combinations of upper case + lower work. Is there any way to avoid this so `NODE/ADD` is thrown a `404` ?

Global redirect has an option for Case sensitive URLs, but I believe its for URL alias and not menu hooks.

Comment: Seems to be a known (probably MySQL-related) problem: http://drupal.org/node/276201

Comment: @Ambidex Thats for URL alias, I have problem with menu hooks, let me check column types for it, may be same issue exists for both